# .innerhtml adds text to p tag instead of replacing via buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating basic math function and have two data and I am showing them using `p` tag using JavaScript

When I click the `button1` it shows correctly but then when i click 'button2' it appends to `data1` answer. like this:

> even = 0,2,4,6,8,10,74,12,88,90
>
> odd = 1,3,5,7,9,,45,65,89,89,45,67

i want it to show only 1 data at a time. for example when i click button one it should show only

> even = 0,2,4,6,8,10
>
> odd = 1,3,5,7,9

and when i click button two it show only

```
even = 74,12,88,90

odd = 45,65,89,89,45,67
```

```js
const data1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const data2 = [45, 65, 74, 89, 89, 12, 45, 67, 88, 90];
var odd = [];
var even = [];

function odd_even(a) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] % 2 == 0) {
      even.push(a[i]);

      document.getElementById('odd').innerText = 'odd = ' + odd;
    } else {
      odd.push(a[i]);

      document.getElementById('even').innerHTML = 'even = ' + even;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick='odd_even(data1);  '>Calculate data1</button>
<button onclick='odd_even(data2);  '>Calculate data2</button>

<p id='even'></p>
<p id='odd'></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first click, you fill `odd` and `even` arrays. And with the second click, you are appending the new values to the old values.

To solve this, you need to initialize `odd` and `even` arrays inside the `odd_even` function.

```js
const data1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const data2 = [45, 65, 74, 89, 89, 12, 45, 67, 88, 90];


function odd_even(a) {

  // Here create new arrays with every click
  var odd = [];
  var even = [];

  for (var i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] % 2 == 0) {
      even.push(a[i]);

      document.getElementById('odd').innerText = 'odd = ' + odd;
    } else {
      odd.push(a[i]);

      document.getElementById('even').innerHTML = 'even = ' + even;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick='odd_even(data1);  '>Calculate data1</button>
<button onclick='odd_even(data2);  '>Calculate data2</button>

<p id='even'></p>
<p id='odd'></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

like this ? :

```js
const data1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const data2 = [45, 65, 74, 89, 89, 12, 45, 67, 88, 90];


function odd_even(a) {
  var odd = [];
var even = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
if (a[i] % 2 == 0) {
  even.push(a[i]);

  document.getElementById('odd').innerHTML = 'odd = ' + odd;
} else {
  odd.push(a[i]);

  document.getElementById('even').innerHTML = 'even = ' + even;
}}}
```

```html
    <button onclick='odd_even(data1);  '>Calculate data1</button>
    <button onclick='odd_even(data2);  '>Calculate data2</button>

<p id='even'></p>
<p id='odd'></p>
```